# CDI Inject Class in JPA Converter (EclipseLink)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, converters, cdi

I have a question, it is possible to use java CDI within a JPA convert?

I'm doing some tests to study and I am not able to inject the objects within my converter:

I'm using a eclipseLink, please see my code, Please analyze my code where I am going wrong? And how can I do this in the best way ?

**Basically to greater understanding, I'll have a session bean that represents my User logged in, this session Bean I have the User TimeZone, I would like to inject this Time Zone within My Converter to write the data to UTC in database**

**My Code:**

*JPA Converter:*  **org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter**

```
package joda;

import inject.qualifier.UserTimeZoneQualifier;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import enumerator.UserType;
import security.UserSession;

@RequestScoped
public class JodaDateTimeUTCConverter implements Converter {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// JUST TEST IT'S WAS INJECT AND REMOVE
private UserSession userSession = new UserSession("America/Mexico_City", UserType.HIGH_HISK);

@Inject
@UserTimeZoneQualifier
String userTimeZone;

//TODO FOR TEST
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS - z - ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ");
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS - z - ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"); 

@Override
public Object convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object dataValue, Session session) {
    // TODO REMOVE
    DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(userSession.getTimeZoneLocale());
    System.out.println("BEFORE OF CONVERTION : " + dt.format(dataValue));
    System.out.println("AFTER  OF CONVERTION : " + dtf.print(new DateTime((Timestamp) dataValue).withZone(timeZone)));
    System.out.println("userTimeZone INJECT" + userTimeZone);


    return dataValue instanceof Date ? new DateTime((Timestamp) dataValue).withZone(timeZone) : null;

}

@Override
public Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object objectValue, Session session) {

    System.out.println("GO TO DB(DATAVALUE)");
    System.out.println("AFTER  OF CONVERTION : " + dtf.print(((DateTime) objectValue).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)));

    return objectValue instanceof DateTime?((DateTime) objectValue).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toLocalDateTime().toDate() : null;
}

@Override
public void initialize(DatabaseMapping mapping, Session session) {
}

@Override
public boolean isMutable() {
    return false;
}

public String getUserTimeZone() {
    return userTimeZone;
}

public void setUserTimeZone(String userTimeZone) {
    this.userTimeZone = userTimeZone;
}
}
```

**My @UserTimeZoneQualifier:**

```
package inject.qualifier;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, TYPE, PARAMETER})
public @interface UserTimeZoneQualifier {

}
```

**And My UserSessionProduce:**

```
package inject;

import inject.qualifier.UserTimeZoneQualifier;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

import enumerator.UserType;
import security.UserSession;

public class UserSessionProduce {

private UserSession userSession;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    this.userSession = new UserSession("America/Mexico_City", UserType.ADMINISTRATOR);
}

@Produces
public UserSession getUserSessionInstance(){
    return this.userSession;
}

@Produces
@UserTimeZoneQualifier
public String getUserSessionTimeZone(){
    return this.userSession.getTimeZoneLocale();
}

@Produces
public UserType getUserType(){
    return this.userSession.getUserType();
}
}
```

**Note:** Outside the injection into the Converter, all the other features are working perfectly, I can eject the EntityManager and other classes as well as persist the data in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.  The spec mandates support for CDI injection in `EntityListener` implementations.  It was not applied to converters.

If you want to access your injection points, you can use `CDI.current()` to get access to a `CDI<Object>` instance.  Using this is just like using `Instance<Object>` - you can do things like `.select(qualifier).select(clazz).get()` to retrieve the bean instance.

If you need to use the qualifier, you need a literal first.

```
public class UserTimeZoneQualifierLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<UserTimeZoneQualifier> implements UserTimeZoneQualifier {

}
```

Then instantiate

```
UserTimeZoneQualifier qualifier = new UserTimeZoneQualifier(); // or use a singleton here.
```

Comment: Could you direct me to a way to do what I wish? How could I work with the User Time Zone logged in to convert or JPA entity? And Many thanks for the advanced support

Comment: I just added some info to my answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Perfect I test : ```String userTimeZone = javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current().select(UserSession.class).get().getTimeZoneLocale();```   and it worked, I could not do with the qualifier, you have an example? I have to do some class that extends the AnnotationLiteral  class?

Comment: Yes, you would need an annotation literal.  I'll that to my answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks for all Support and Attention @John Ament